# RaspberryPiBeacon Android detection App

Tags: android, ibeacon, altbeacon, beacon, android-applicationinfo

I am building an Android beacon detection application, I am using my raspberryPi as a ibeacon, I followed the commands from this [link](https://learn.adafruit.com/pibeacon-ibeacon-with-a-raspberry-pi/adding-ibeacon-data). 
I am having some trouble detecting the beacon with my code,I am using the altbeacon library. I am guessing it has to do with the beacon parser statement which is as follows...

```
beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().            setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));
```

I am guessing it is not detected because I am not using an estimote beacon. what would be the parse value for "m:2-3 = beac" in my case since I am using a raspberry pi as a beacon?

Is there something you can suggest in this case?

Answer (score 1):

The problem may not be with the Android code -- it may be with the Raspberry Pi beacon transmitter.  I would try first using an off-the-shelf Android beacon detection app like [Locate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.radiusnetworks.locate&hl=en).  This app is based on the same [Android Beacon Library](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/), so if it can detect it, your app should be able to detect it as well.

If that app cannot detect the beacon, the most likely explanation is that there is something wrong with the Raspberry Pi transmitter.  Double check the Pi beacon tutorial you followed, and verify you are using a compatible Bluetooth LE dongle.

Full disclosure:  I am the author of the Locate app and the lead developer on the Android Beacon Library open source project.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, My pibeacon is being detected by other android beacon detection applications from the playstore. It seems like I am having an only with my application it does not enter the didEnterRegion() method when I debug it with logs.